# templated class can't redefine operator[]

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I've this class

```
namespace baseUtils {

template<typename AT>
class growVector {

        int size;
        AT **arr;
        AT* defaultVal;

    public:

        growVector(int size, AT* defaultVal );   //Expects number of elements (5) and default value (NULL)
        AT*& operator[](unsigned pos);
        int length();
        void reset(int pos);    //Resets an element to default value
        void reset();           //Resets all elements to default value
        ~growVector();
};

}
```

and this is the implementation for operator[]

```
template<typename AT>
AT*& growVector<AT>::operator [](unsigned pos){
    if (pos >= size){
        int newSize = size*2;
        AT** newArr = new AT*[newSize];
        memcpy(newArr, arr, sizeof(AT)*size);
        for (int i = size; i<newSize; i++)
            newArr[i] = defaultVal;
        size = newSize;
        delete arr;
        arr = newArr;
    }
    return arr[pos];
}
```

(yes I do realize i don't check if size*2 >= pos... but that's not the point now)
if I use it in code like:

```
int main() {

    growVector<char> gv();
    char* x = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i< 50; i++){
        gv[i] = x;
    }
    gv.reset();
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler says

```
../src/base.cpp:98: warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic
../src/base.cpp:98: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*(gv + ((unsigned int)i))’
../src/base.cpp:98: error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘baseUtils::growVector<char>()’ in assignment
```

referring to the line gv[i] = x; (seems like it doesn't see the redefinition of [])

Why???? What am I missing?

---

After correcting the constructor problem I've the linker sayng:

```
/home/dario/workspace/base/Debug/../src/base.cpp:95: undefined reference to `baseUtils::growVector<char>::growVector(int, char*)'
/home/dario/workspace/base/Debug/../src/base.cpp:98: undefined reference to `baseUtils::growVector<char>::operator[](unsigned int)'
/home/dario/workspace/base/Debug/../src/base.cpp:100: undefined reference to `baseUtils::growVector<char>::reset()'
/home/dario/workspace/base/Debug/../src/base.cpp:101: undefined reference to `baseUtils::growVector<char>::~growVector()'
/home/dario/workspace/base/Debug/../src/base.cpp:101: undefined reference to `baseUtils::growVector<char>::~growVector()'
```

like it cannot link... why??? :O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is your declaration

```
growVector<char> gv();
```

The compiler interprets this as declaring a function called `gv` which returns a `growVector<char>`, not as an object as you indend. Since there isn't a default constructor, this wouldn't compile anyway. Change it to:

```
growVector<char> gv(0,0);
```

Comment: lol i really wasn't looking at it... sorry what a shame... XD

Answer (score 4):

The compiler thinks this line

```
growVector<char> gv();
```

is declaring a function, rather than a variable. Drop the `()` and things should work.

Answer (score 1):

I just would like to point out that it is a good practice to have two versions of subscript [] operator in the class: const (which will be used for r-value) and non-const.
You have implemented non-const version but it can not be used in const functions or in any function that receive instance of your class as const reference or pointer pointer to const.